# How to install mailman when it needs an older version of Python?

Tags: ubuntu, python, mailman

I am working on an install of mailman 3.0.3 on Ubuntu Server 16.04 which ships with Python 3.5.1 and 2.7.11. Per Barry Warsaw that version of mailman requires Python 3.4.n. https://gitlab.com/mailman/mailman/issues/184

My choices seem to be:

```
downgrade 3.5.1  
install 3.4.4 in parallel  
use conda to create a virtual environment  
another approach???
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: How were you installing MailMan 3.0.3?  Via `pip` or via `apt-get`?

Comment: I used pip for the install.